# How do I delete or skip over a word or a line of text in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

On a Windows system I can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd> plus <kbd>backspace</kbd> or one of the arrow keys. But this does not seem to work in an Ubuntu terminal. How do I do it?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I use ctrl+arrow key to skip words, and alt+backspace to remove last word, but it'll depend on which virtual terminal program you are using (I use `qterminal`) and you were vague saying a ubuntu terminal (not which or if you mean the default, and then default desktop? or default server?)

Comment: I just tested and those keys work on `gnome-terminal` too assuming GUI is being used (I missed your tagging `gnome-terminal` sorry)

Comment: A nice standard shortcut in Bash is `Ctrl + W` which cuts the previous word. I have remapped so `Ctrl + E` cuts the next word. This combined with `Ctrl + Arrows` gives good editing capability.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks. Actually I wasn't sure if it is called gnome-terminal since I am new to using Ubuntu. It is just the default terminal that appears when I press `ctrl+alt+t`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete a word before the cursor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. This is actually kind of a "cut to clipboard". Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> ("yank") to paste it back elsewhere. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> will cut to the end of the line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to the start of the line.

To skip over a word backwards, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to skip over a word forwards.

These keys [and many others](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/) universally work in bash in your terminal emulator, in a virtual console or over an ssh connection.

In the gnome terminal emulator, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/right</kbd> will jump over words left or right. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will delete the word on the left, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> will delete the word to the right from the current position.

Answer (score 3):

moving:

- to the end of the command: ctrl-e
- to the begin of the command: ctrl-a
- forward a word: alt-f
- backword a word: alt-b

deleting:

- from current cursor position to the end of word: ald-d
- from current cursor position to the begin of word: clt-w

example:

- touch .gitignore
- cltr-a (go to the begin)
- alt-d (delete "touch")
- type "code" => code .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

For deleting a line in ubuntu terminal,

1. place the cursor on the line you want to delete.
2. press "dd"
3. The line will be deleted.